# Cómo mostrar un optgroup dependiendo del select selecionado con jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-validate, html-select

Necesito averiguar cómo hacer con jQuery que, dependiendo de qué ***option*** elija en el ***select #provincia***, me muestre un ***optgroup*** determinado en el siguiente ***select #localidad*** y me oculte el resto o no me los muestre.

Gracias!

```
<label for="provincia">Selecciona provincia: </label> <select name="provincia" id="provincia">
                <option value="valencia">Valencia</option>
                <option value="castellon">Castellón</option>
                <option value="alicante">Alicante</option>
            </select><br><br>

            <label for="localidad">Localidad:</label> <select name="localidad" id="localidad">
                <optgroup label="valencia">
                    <option value="mislata">Mislata</option>
                    <option value="quart">Quart de Poblet</option>
                    <option value="alboraya">Alboraya</option>
                </optgroup>
                <optgroup label="castellon">
                    <option value="villarreal">Villarreal</option>
                    <option value="onda">Onda</option>
                    <option value="vinaroz">Vinaroz</option>
                </optgroup>
                <optgroup label="alicante">
                    <option value="alcoy">ALcoy</option>
                    <option value="elda">Elda</option>
                    <option value="torrevieja">Torrevieja</option>
                </optgroup>
            </select><br><br>
```

Answer (score 1):

Puedes esconder todos los `optgroup` y mostrar el que quieres una vez seleccionado el valor de provincia.  Algo asi:

```js
$("#provincia").change(function() {
  var val = $(this).val();
  $("#localidad").children("optgroup").hide();
  $("#localidad").children("optgroup[label='" + val + "']").show();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<label for="provincia">Selecciona provincia: </label> <select name="provincia" id="provincia">
                <option value="valencia">Valencia</option>
                <option value="castellon">Castellón</option>
                <option value="alicante">Alicante</option>
            </select><br><br>

            <label for="localidad">Localidad:</label> <select name="localidad" id="localidad">
                <optgroup label="valencia">
                    <option value="mislata">Mislata</option>
                    <option value="quart">Quart de Poblet</option>
                    <option value="alboraya">Alboraya</option>
                </optgroup>
                <optgroup label="castellon">
                    <option value="villarreal">Villarreal</option>
                    <option value="onda">Onda</option>
                    <option value="vinaroz">Vinaroz</option>
                </optgroup>
                <optgroup label="alicante">
                    <option value="alcoy">ALcoy</option>
                    <option value="elda">Elda</option>
                    <option value="torrevieja">Torrevieja</option>
                </optgroup>
            </select><br><br>
```

Comment: Efectivamente es lo que buscaba. Muchas gracias!